# How to restart a systemd service with salt?

Tags: salt-stack

I am trying to build an `.sls` file which will always restart a service:

```
systemd-resolved:
  service.running:
    - restart: True
```

When deployed, this gives

---

```
      ID: systemd-resolved
Function: service.running
  Result: True
 Comment: The service systemd-resolved is already running
 Started: 23:46:49.999789
Duration: 53.068 ms
 Changes:
```

This is correct, the service is already running. What I was trying to convey with this command is to restart it. How to do that?

Note: I would like to avoid, if possible, an explicit command to be ran (as I feel it i snot very salt-like - this should rather be handled by the appropriate module):

```
'systemctl restart systemd-resolved':
  cmd.run
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want your service to reload you need to set `reload: True` instead.
Beside, If you only want to restart the service if there is any change in any other state, you need to use `watch` instead. 
for instance,

```
systemd-resolved:
  service.running:
    - enable: True
    - reload: True
    - watch:
      - pkg: <abc>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this does not work if the service does not have the execreload command defined in the service file.  The only way around this that I have found is to use cmd.run and systemctl restart service.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).